# how to get UnboundID execution error on async calls?

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

How can I listen to error when running async actions?
e.g "no connection" or error in query (if there is such a thing)

I am running the following:

- create a connection
- pause the program
- disconnecting network cable
- running asyncSearch

the search fails but I have no indication for it.

Comment: I have added the example to the original question.

Comment: Please post the relevant code fragment(s).

Comment: I am looking for that code. I couldn't find error handling code in async calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following classes:

- `AsyncCompareResultListener`
- `AsyncResultListener`
- `AsyncSearchResultListener`